Internal server error: Failed to load url in virtual:remix/server-build. Does the file exist?
I've recently renamed a route in my remix app, and for configuration/path resolution reasons I can't fully understand, it can't seem to find the route.
Here is the newly added route: app/routes/events.\eventId.tsx

Error:

[vite] Internal server error: Failed to load url /app/routes/events./eventId.tsx (resolved id: /app/routes/events./eventId.tsx) in virtual:remix/server-build. Does the file exist?
  at loadAndTransform (file:///home/remixapp/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-DyBnyoVI.js:51857:17)
  at async instantiateModule (file:///home/remixapp/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-DyBnyoVI.js:52816:44)


I've tried looking into the config files to see if I needed to add any paths to a path resolver of some kind.
Currently, I've tried adding the path above explicitly to the include array in the tsconfig.json and content array in tailwind.config.ts.
tsconfig.json
{
  "include": [
    "**/*.ts",
    "**/*.tsx",
    "**/.server/**/*.ts",
    "**/.server/**/*.tsx",
    "**/.client/**/*.ts",
    "**/.client/**/*.tsx",
  ],
  "compilerOptions": {
    "lib": ["DOM", "DOM.Iterable", "ES2022"],
    "types": ["@remix-run/node", "vite/client"],
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "jsx": "react-jsx",
    "module": "ESNext",
    "moduleResolution": "Bundler",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "target": "ES2022",
    "strict": true,
    "allowJs": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "paths": {
      "~/*": ["./app/*"]
    },

    // Vite takes care of building everything, not tsc.
    "noEmit": true
  }
}

tailwind.config.ts
import type { Config } from "tailwindcss";

export default {
  content: ["./app/**/{**,.client,.server}/**/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}"],
  theme: {
    extend: {
      fontFamily: {
        sans: [
          '"Inter"',
          "ui-sans-serif",
          "system-ui",
          "sans-serif",
          '"Apple Color Emoji"',
          '"Segoe UI Emoji"',
          '"Segoe UI Symbol"',
          '"Noto Color Emoji"',
        ],
      },
    },
  },
  plugins: [],
} satisfies Config;

I've successfully completed the Remix Tutorial, but comparing and contrasting the final output of the tutorial and my current app, it's not immediately apparent to me what I'm missing.

Error says it can't find the file "/app/routes/events./eventId.tsx", but you've named your file "/app/routes/events.\eventId.tsx", so the server cannot find the correct file based on the URL path.
The escaping "\" character was used in the terminal when making the file via CLI: touch app/routes/contacts.\$contactId.tsx.

Create the app/routes directory and contact route module
mkdir app/routes
touch app/routes/contacts.\$contactId.tsx


Read down a bit further:

In the Remix route file convention, . will create a / in the URL and $
makes a segment dynamic.
We just created a route that will match URLs that look like this:

/contacts/123
/contacts/abc


They created a file named "app/routes/contacts.$contactId.tsx". In this case then it seems the issue is using "\" instead of "$" in the file name.
Rename your file to "events.$eventId.tsx".
